# Remove everything except period and numbers from string regex in R

Tags: regex, r, string, stringr

I know there are many questions on stack overflow regarding regex but I cannot accomplish this one easy task with the available help I've seen. Here's my data:

```
a<-c("Los Angeles, CA","New York, NY", "San Jose, CA")
b<-c("c(34.0522, 118.2437)","c(40.7128, 74.0059)","c(37.3382, 121.8863)")

df<-data.frame(a,b)
df
                a                    b
1 Los Angeles, CA c(34.0522, 118.2437)
2    New York, NY  c(40.7128, 74.0059)
3    San Jose, CA c(37.3382, 121.8863)
```

I would like to remove the everything but the numbers and the period (i.e. remove "c", ")" and "(". This is what I've tried thus far:

```
str_replace(df$b,"[^0-9.]","" )
[1] "(34.0522, 118.2437)" "(40.7128, 74.0059)"  "(37.3382, 121.8863)"

str_replace(df$b,"[^\\d\\)]+","" )
[1] "34.0522, 118.2437)" "40.7128, 74.0059)"  "37.3382, 121.8863)"
```

Not sure what's left to try. I would like to end up with the following:

```
 [1] "34.0522, 118.2437" "40.7128, 74.0059"  "37.3382, 121.8863"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have R code as text? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: I think it may be better to have it as a list instead of storing as a string again. i.e. `lapply(str_extract_all(df$b, "[0-9.]+"), as.numeric)`

Comment: don't know why the code is like that, I wrote a function to batch geocode and for some reason it occasionally spits out a data frame that I transpose, the transpose function turns creates this odd "r code as text" issue. Even weirder it doesn't do this to all datasets.I split a data frame in half and ran a batch geocode on 1 and a batch geocode on the other and the first half of the original dataset transposes just fine but the second half creates this odd feature. I've run that question by almost half a dozen people and no one can figure it out.

Comment: @akrun My final product needs to be a data frame with three columns , the name of the cities, then two columns -one for lat and one for long. I was hoping that with the help of the fine people on stack overflow I could get over the first barrier of stripping the non necessary characters, then I was just going to split the column into two at the space between the two coordinates.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian  If you need it as two columns `cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(str_extract_all(df$b, "[0-9.]+"), as.numeric)))`

Comment: OK, so you have a problem with your preceding code and instead of fixing it you try to treat the symptom. Not a smart strategy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
gsub("[\\c|\\(|\\)]", "",df$b)
#[1] "34.0522, 118.2437" "40.7128, 74.0059"  "37.3382, 121.8863"
```

Answer (score 10):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you want:

```
df$b <- gsub("[^[:digit:]., ]", "", df$b)
```

or:

```
df$b <- strsplit(gsub("[^[:digit:]. ]", "", df$b), " +")
> df
                a                 b
1 Los Angeles, CA 34.0522, 118.2437
2    New York, NY  40.7128, 74.0059
3    San Jose, CA 37.3382, 121.8863
```

or if you want all the "numbers" as a numeric vector:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^[:digit:]. ]", "", df$b), " +")))
[1]  34.0522 118.2437  40.7128  74.0059  37.3382 121.8863
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a regular expression solution, but a simple one.

The elements of `b` are R expressions, so loop over each element, parsing it, then creating the string you want.

```
vapply(
  b, 
  function(bi) 
  {
    toString(eval(parse(text = bi)))
  }, 
  character(1)
)
```

Comment: Tried that with the following: ``vapply(
  df$b, 
  function(bi) 
  {
    toString(eval(parse(text = bi)))
  }, 
  character(1)
)`` and got ``"1" "3" "2"``

Comment: `df$b` is a `factor`.  Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, or coerce the column to character with `as.character`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `str_extract_all` from `stringr`.  Extract the numeric part using `str_extract_all` into a `list`, convert to `numeric`, `rbind` the `list` elements and `cbind` it with the first column of 'df'

```
library(stringr)
cbind(df[1], do.call(rbind, 
      lapply(str_extract_all(df$b, "[0-9.]+"), as.numeric)))
```